# how run a function code that is written in another file and call in another file sequentially in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to run my function as I wrote it, but as we know node.js is asynchronous language, so the code in the run in an async manner here my problem starts in my code I want to execute each line of code in the sequence of as they write.

Now my question is that how to run a function sequentially in Node.js.

**Here is my code of index.js file where i calling function**

```
var request = require('request');
var requestHandling = require('../routes/request_handling_functions');

router.get("/example1", function (req, res) {

var result = 
 requestHandling.requestMethodGet('http://localhost:8083/getUserInfo/865c2c25-d9e7-412d-a064-326bd66c9e9c', res);
    console.log("===RESULT=====");
    console.log(result);
});
```

in above code I want to call the requestMethodGet function first, and after that, I want to console the result of that function. but whole things went wrong it executes the console.log lines first then it calls the function.

> My output in the console is

```
===RESULT=====
undefined
```

> Here is my file in which i define that function

var request = require('request');
    var log = require('log4js').getLogger("index");

```
module.exports = {
requestMethodGet: async function (url, res) {

    //SET ALL THESE PARATMETER TO MAKE REQUEST
    request.get({url: url}, function (e, r, body) {

        var errorResult = module.exports.validateResponseeData(e);

        console.log("====errorResult===in===Get==method====");
        console.log(errorResult);
        if (errorResult != "continue") {
            console.log("===im in not continue");
            res.send(errorResult);
        } else {

            //LOGING THE RESPONSE BODY
            log.info('body:', body);

            var responseData = JSON.parse(body);


console.log("======AUTHTOKEN=========DATA=====================");
            console.log('error:', e);
            console.log('statusCode:', r && r.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);
            console.log("====================================");
            console.log(responseData);

            res.send(responseData);
        }
    });
}
```

if any help is needed regarding this question or wants more information, then please inform me.

Comment: you have to use callback in your case you can check this link https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Comment: I update my question please check

Answer (score -5):

You can create your async function as promise function and then make it can be accessed sequentially using async await and try catch method javascript.

You can see this information for better information
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: can u provide my an example with my code or dummy code